# Why is Js altering variables to Nan and messing up other vector

Tags: javascript, nan

So I'm new to Javascript, I'm trying to learn it as fast as I can by searching a lot! But I can't seem to find any solutions.
To sum, I'm writing a program in Js that detects collisions between balls and deals with them.
Each ball has a "moveDirection" vector that represents the direction that the ball is going, a position vector that saves the ball's current position and a velocity (scalar). All vectors have 3 variables(x,y,z) and the ball only moves in the x and z variables.
Im trying to deal with the collision between balls in this function:

```
function reactToCollision(b1, b2) {
    let pos1 = b1.position.clone();
    let pos2 = b2.position.clone();
    let v1 = b1.moveDirection.clone();
    let v2 = b2.moveDirection.clone();

    let a = (v1.sub(v2)).dot((pos1.sub(pos2)));
    let b = Math.pow((pos1.sub(pos2)).length, 2);
    let c = (pos1.sub(pos2)).multiplyScalar(-a / b);
    b1.moveDirection.addScalar(c);

    let d = (v2.sub(v1)).dot(pos2.sub(pos1));
    let e = Math.pow((pos2.sub(pos1)).length, 2);
    let f = (pos2.sub(pos1)).multiplyScalar(-d / e);
    b2.moveDirection.addScalar(f);

    b2.velocity = b1.velocity;
}
```

This is where I call the function:

```
function moveBall(ball, deltatime) {
    let ballCollided = collision(ball);
    if (ballCollided != null) {
        reactToCollision(ball, ballCollided);
        if (findBall(ballCollided.name) == null) {
            movingBalls.push(ballCollided.name);
        }
    }
    ball.position.x += ball.moveDirection.x * ball.velocity;
    ball.position.z += -ball.moveDirection.z * ball.velocity;
    ball.velocity -= deltatime * friction;
}
```

The problem is that the ball's position.x and position.z is now NaN and the moveDirection vector is now very strange, like this:

```
x: "-0.23202599585056305[object Object]"
y: "0[object Object]"
z: "0.9727095907821058[object Object]"
```

I would really appreciate someone's help and patience to help me solve this problem!
Thank you very much if you came this far!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know where you have the issue since you call many different methods, but here are some basic rules what can mess up your code and can drive to these results:
If you do any arithmetic operation (except `+`) with a number and other types then you will get `NaN` like:

```js
console.log(51 * 'hello');   // prints NaN
console.log(51 / undefined); // prints NaN
console.log(51 - {});        // prints NaN
```

`+` is a bit different, here JS will try to convert them into a common type, which is `string` in our case. When you convert an Object to string then you will get `'[object Object]'` so

```js
console.log(53 + 'Hello'); // prints "53Hello"
console.log(53 + {});      // prints "53[object Object]"
console.log(53 + [1, 2]);  // prints "531,2" - [1, 2] is converted into '1,2'
```